# calling more than one function in STL algorithm

Tags: c++, boost, c++11

The classical example using STL algorithms:

```
void foo(int){};
vector<int> collection;
collection.push_back(3);
collection.push_back(4);
... etc.

std::for_each(collection.begin(), collection.end(), bind(foo, _1));
```

But what if we have more then one function, which needs to be called with the same argument values:

```
void bar(int){};
void beer(int){};
... etc.
```

Repeating for_each algorithm every time with different functions is not option. I need more elegant solution.

Comment: I was thinking also about boost::lambda or boost::phoenix, are they create less readable expression?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since you tagged the question with `C++11`, then you can use lambda as:

```
std::for_each(collection.begin(), collection.end(), [](int a)
{
   bar(a);    
   beer(a);
});
```

I recall that C++11 has `std::begin` and `std::end` as free functions, which should be preferred over the member functions:

```
std::for_each(std::begin(collection), std::end(collection), [](int a)
{
   bar(a);    
   beer(a);
});
```

The rationale why the free functions should be preferred is because now if, for example, you change the type of the collection to simple array (say, `int collection[100]`), then the above code would work just fine without changing a single character. With the new Standard C++, the free functions are going to be used more uniformly than the member functions.

Or, you can use *range-based* `for` loop as:

```
for(int a : collection)
{
   bar(a);    
   beer(a);
}
```

Ah! It looks even better. Neat and clean, with no `begin` and `end` at all.

Answer (score 5):

This would be a nice place to use lambdas:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

void bar(int){};
void beer(int){};

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> collection;
    collection.push_back(3);
    collection.push_back(4);
    std::for_each(collection.begin(), collection.end(),
                  [](int i) {bar(i); beer(i);});
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this, perhaps?

```
void bunch_of_functions( int arg )
{
    foo( arg );
    bar( arg );
    foobar( arg );
}

std::for_each(
    collection.begin(), collection.end()
  , bind(bunch_of_functions, _1)
);
```